# Distance between two locations isn't right

Tags: android, maps, distance, haversine

I have used the algorithm on http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html to find the distance between two points.

My two points are

```
long1 = 51.507467;
lat1 = -0.08776;

long2 = 51.508736;
lat2 = -0.08612;
```

According to [Movable Type Script](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) the answer is 0.1812km

My application gives the result (`d`) as 0.230km

Check Haversine formula: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

```
    double R = 6371; // earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
    double dLat =  Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);

    double dLon =  Math.toRadians(long2-long1); 
    a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * 
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    double d = R * c;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why to reinvent your own distance calculator, there is one built into the [Location](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/Location.html) class.

Check out

```
distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results) 
Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between them.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is correct. The distance given those longitudes and latitudes should produce a distance of `0.230 km`. The normal input for coordinates, however, is (latitude, longitude). Putting them in backwards (longitude, latitude) produces the incorrect distance of `0.1812 km`.

Comment: Oh... little embarrassed. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public double CalculationByDistance(GeoPoint StartP, GeoPoint EndP) {  
  double lat1 = StartP.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;  
  double lat2 = EndP.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;  
  double lon1 = StartP.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;  
  double lon2 = EndP.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;  
  double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);  
  double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);  
  double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +  
     Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *  
     Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);  
  double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));  
  return Radius * c;  
 }
```

Ally your concept was right.May be a little bit chang in this line `double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));`